# Is there a way to dynamically change the range used for a calculation in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rank

I have a dataset like this -

| slice | time_id | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 10 |
| 2 | 0 | 20 |
| 3 | 0 | 30 |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | 25 |
| 1 | 2 | 30 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 2 | 20 |

What will be the best method to get a rank column, which computes the rank for slices corresponding to the previous time_id?
For instance, the output for the same table should look something like this -

| slice | time_id | weight | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 20 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 30 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 25 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 30 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 20 | 1 |

I tried the excel rank function (had to manually set the rank range in the function, rank(slice, range) for every time_id), but it is too much manual work and I have slices and time periods in the hundreds. So what will be the best way to achieve this?

My objective is to find the top n slices for a time_id, based on weight during time_id-1

Comment: Ranks are set to 0 since that is the initial state and the rank for time_id = 0 doesn't matter for my calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution from Microsoft support and it works-

Put this formula in E2 and drag down
=IF($B2=0,0,COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$100,INDEX($B$2:$B$100,ROW(2:2)-4),$C$2:$C$100,">"&INDEX($C$2:$C$100,ROW(2:2)-4))+1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).